# Retrieving Json via HTML request from Jboss server

Tags: java, json, jboss, httpurlconnection, socketexception

I am running into a `java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file` from server when I am trying to query some JSON from my JBoss server. I am hoping someone can spot where I am going wrong.  Or does anyone have any suggestions of a better way to pull this JSON from my Jboss server?

```
try{
        URL u = new URL("http://localhost:9990/management/subsystem/datasources/data-source/MySQLDS/statistics?read-resource&include-runtime=true&recursive=true");
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        String encoded = Base64.encode(("username"+":"+"password").getBytes());
        c.setRequestMethod("POST");
        c.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        c.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        c.setReadTimeout(5000);
        c.connect();

        int status = c.getResponseCode();  // throws the exception here

        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(status);
                break;
        }



    }  catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I was looking into setting the content length but even if I set the content length, When running the debugger it never adds content length to the request params.

Comment: I found a lib to do all this for me. It was called Resty. Allows for getting JSON from a URL and add authentication.